# Angular image tag src binding localhost url

Tags: angular

Im using angular 7 and I want to add image from other project.

My local project domain url is `localhost:5700`. Here i tried to use image of other project like below.

```
<img [src]="/var/www/html/mvf/assets/img/image.png">
```

But it is taking url like

```
http://localhost:5700/var/www/html/mvf/assets/img/image.png
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using relative paths or normalized paths as explained below:

> All we have to do is reference these images in our templates with a
>   path that starts inside the src folder.
>
> For instance, if we have an image at src/assets/img/logo.png, we would
>   add this to our template.

```
template: `
  <img src="assets/img/logo.png">
`
```

Or you can use relative path like `../../assets/image/logo.png`.

[Blog reference](https://scotch.io/courses/build-your-first-angular-website/adding-an-imagelogo-in-angular)

Comment: what if the image is in some other directory other than the project directory?

Comment: Usually asset folder is available at the root that's why having relative path helps with your index.html being at root, if it's in some other directory I'll suggest either move it to assets or either host your images on some 3rd party like s3 or cloudinary to avoid having relative paths.